# Error inflating class com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderImageViewImageView

Tags: android, baseadapter, loader

Error Trace:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            Process: com.example.user.itekit, PID: 23028
>                                                                            android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #87: Error
>   inflating class
>   com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderImageViewImageView
>                                                                                at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
>                                                                                at
>   com.example.user.itekit.ListbaseAdapter.getView(ListbaseAdapter.java:74)
>                                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2842)
>                                                                                at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1290)
>                                                                                at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1202)
>                                                                                at
>   com.example.user.itekit.ExpandableHightListView.onMeasure(ExpandableHightListView.java:36)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
>                                                                                at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1835)
>                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:725)
>                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:616)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
>                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
>                                                                                at
>   android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:2015)
>                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:484)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
>                                                                                at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
>                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
>                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
>                                                                                at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1835)
>                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:725)
>                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:616)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
>                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
>                                                                                at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1835)
>                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:725)
>                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:616)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
>                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2881)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2237)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1537)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1180)
>                                                                                at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6558)
>                                                                                at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
>                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
>                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
>                                                                                at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback

Tried using the Loader View for android from https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4243#!description .

The ideal situation is : to have the loading effect as the link shows to my images & text on view.

The issue comes that whenever I try to implement it through an adapter I get an error as per the title states

Snippet of the code is as given below:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();


        viewHolder.image = (LoaderImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        viewHolder.title = (LoaderTextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        viewHolder.subtitle = (LoaderTextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        viewHolder.shop = (LoaderTextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.shop);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);




    }else {

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }


    BeanclassTourCategory bean = (BeanclassTourCategory)getItem(position);

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(bean.getImage())
            .fit()
            .into(viewHolder.image);

    viewHolder.title.setText(bean.getTitle());
    viewHolder.subtitle.setText(bean.getSubtitle());
    viewHolder.shop.setText(bean.getShop());

    return convertView;
}
```

A) Is there a possible solution to this Error?

B) Are there any alternative Loader views to be easily implemented with adapters?

Comment: Don't just tell us the error.  Post the full stack trace.  Especially in a case like this, where its likely that was a cascading error from the real one.

Comment: Also on your question B-  totally off topic on this site.  "Better" is an opinion based question, and depends on dozens of factors of individual app needs.  It isn't possible for us to answer that for you in any general sense, at best we can tell if a piece of code does what it says or not.

Comment: @GabeSechan Edited as adviced,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I didn't see this the first time:

Error inflating class com.elyeproj.loaderviewlibrary.LoaderImageViewImageView

You called something in your xml LoaderImageViewImageView instead of LoaderImageView

Comment: Thanks A lot. Silly as it is, that was it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove src of the component LoaderImageViewImageView in the xml